# Access multiple camera raspberry pi

Tags: python, camera, opencv

so now I'm working with camera in raspberry pi. I'm using Arducam multiple cameras board V2.2 to use multiple cameras. From the tutorial, it uses I2C for each camera with different GPIO port. With this code, I successfully show the video stream using cv2.imshow with the first port camera:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import RPi.GPIO as gp
import os

gp.setwarnings(False)
gp.setmode(gp.BOARD)

gp.setup(7,gp.OUT)
gp.setup(11,gp.OUT)
gp.setup(12,gp.OUT)
gp.setup(13,gp.OUT)

i2c = "i2cset -y 1 0x70 0x00 0x04"
os.system(i2c)
gp.output(7, False)
gp.output(11, False)
gp.output(12, True)

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

time.sleep(0.1)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array

    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Now I want to show other cameras in different window. Can anyone help me how to do it? I'm not using the test code from Arducam because it used GUI to combine all cameras into one window.

P.S.: this is the I2C for all camera ports.

```
#Camera A
i2c = "i2cset -y 1 0x70 0x00 0x04"
os.system(i2c)
gp.output(7, False)
gp.output(11, False)
gp.output(12, True)

#Camera B   
i2c = "i2cset -y 1 0x70 0x00 0x05"
os.system(i2c)
gp.output(7, True)
gp.output(11, False)
gp.output(12, True)

#Camera C
i2c = "i2cset -y 1 0x70 0x00 0x06"
os.system(i2c)
gp.output(7, False)
gp.output(11, True)
gp.output(12, False)
    
#Camera D
i2c = "i2cset -y 1 0x70 0x00 0x07"
os.system(i2c)
gp.output(7, True)
gp.output(11, True)
gp.output(12, False)
```

Thank you.